# How to chain Comparators with classes of same interface?

Tags: java, generics, comparison

I want to create a comparator that can take any comparator of classes sharing the same interface. But the following code does not work:

```
public class MainApp {
    public void test() {
        ComparatorChain<TestInterface> comp = new ComparatorChain<>();
        comp.addComparator(new TestAComparator());
        // ERROR: The method addComparator(Comparator<TestInterface>) in the type ComparatorChain<TestInterface> is not applicable for the arguments (MainApp.TestAComparator)
    }

    //more comparators for each class implementing TestInterface
    class TestAComparator implements Comparator<TestClassA> { //TestClassA implements TestInterface
        @Override
        public int compare(TestClassA o1, TestClassA o2) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public interface TestInterface {

}

//more classes that implement this interface
public class TestClassA implements TestInterface {

}
```

What is wrong here? How can I achieve this comparison?

Comment: Can you share the code of the `ComparatorChain` class?

Comment: I don't think that a ComparatorChain is what you need here. A ComparatorChain will run each comparator in the list of comparators until one of them returns a non-zero value

Comment: Or you could use Java 8 which has this support built in.

Comment: Define "does not work" precisely, including any error message you get, or any unexpected behavior.

Comment: The comparator is `org.apache.commons.collections4.comparators.ComparatorChain` and I'm restricted to java7. The "does not work" refers to the error in the comments, @see: "// ERROR: The method addComparator(Comparator<TestInterface>) .. is not applicable for the arguments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. A `ComparatorChain<TestInterface>` accepts comparators that are able to compare instances of any class implementing `TestInterface`. You're trying to add to the chain a comparator that is able to compare instances of `TestClassA` only. So if the chain accepted this comparator, it would fail when comparing anything other than TestClassA instances, which would break its type-safety.

What you want to do is simply impossible, because you can't compare instances of `TestClassB` with a comparator of `TestClassA`, even if `TestClassA` and `TestClassB` share a common interface.